# Update field in model for all "submodels" changes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know how to update some field of ForeignKey. For example when I want change last_modified field every time if Configuration or SomeOtherImportantClass is changed:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class SomeOtherImportantClass(models.Model):
    conf = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)
    important_number = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        conf.last_modified = timezone.now() # I'm not sure if it is necessary
        conf.save()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but in my real situation the Cofiguration model is a ForeignKey for more than 30 other models. In each of them I want to update configuration.last_modified field for every change performed on them or when another model (which has ForeignKey to some model which has ForeignKey do Configuration) is changed. So it looks like that:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class A(models.Model):
    conf = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)  # conf.last_modified must be updated on every change on A model object.

class B(models.Model):
    conf = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)  # same

...

class Z(models.Model):
    conf = models.ForeignKey(Configuration)  # same

class AA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.TextField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
...

class ZZ(models.Model)
    some_field = models.TextField()
    z = models.ForeignKey(Z)
```

so even if AA object field "some_field" is changed I want to update last_modified Configuration field. Is there any recursion way to declare it once in Configuration or somewhere else?

**UPDATE:** Great-granchilds like AAA and AAAA classes can exist too.

Comment: Your classes A-Z should all be subclasses of one abstract class that has the `conf` foreign key and the save method to modify `self.conf.last_modified`. Then all your classes AA-ZZ should be subclasses of one abstract class where you create a class attribute to indicate what is the parent class (the fk that leads to conf), and you can write the save method using that attribute (if set). Finally in each AA-ZZ class you set this attribute, e.g. `parent_field = 'z'` in ZZ.

Comment: You could use an abstract base class from which to derive `A` to `Z` and a different one for `AA` to `ZZ`, so you code special in those groups of 26 models only once (DRY). The ForeignKey field `a` in `AA` would need to have the same name as the one `z` in `ZZ` for this to work (absent any complex metaclassing magic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) as explained in the docs. For A-Z it's quite easy:

```
class ConfigurationChild(Model):

    conf = ForeignKey(Configuration)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self):
        self.conf.last_modified = ...
        self.conf.save()
        super().save()

class A(ConfigurationChild):
    # other fields, without conf
```

For the grand-children it's a bit more complex because then don't have a reference to `conf` directly. Set an attribute on the base class that you populate on each child class:

```
class ConfigurationDescendant(Model):

    conf_handle = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_conf(self):
        if not self.conf_handle:
            return None  # or raise an error
        parent = getattr(self, self.conf_handle)
        if isinstance(parent, ConfigurationDescendant):
            return parent.get_conf()  # recursion
        else:
            # reached `ConfigurationChild` class, might want to check this
            return parent.conf if parent else None  

    def save(self):
        conf = self.get_conf()  
        # you might want to handle the case that the attribute is None
        if conf:
            conf.last_modified = ...
            conf.save()
        super().save()

class AA(ConfigurationDescendant):
    conf_handle = 'a'

    a = ForeignKey(A)

class AAA(ConfigurationDescendant):
    conf_handle = 'aa'
    aa = ForeignKey(AA)
```

The above code will handle the case when the chain breaks because `conf_handle` is missing on one of the parents. In which case `None` is returned and nothing happens. I'm not checking if the handle is set wrongly (i.e. not pointing in the right direction towards the parent `Configuration`), that will raise an exception which you probably want so you can catch mistakes.

Comment: It is some way. I added update. Will it be simple for more complex tree with more generations?

Comment: It would be similar for the next generation, create an abstract class and define how `Configuration` is related to the model. But in that case I'm wondering if your model structure makes sense in the first place. You shouldn't have generations and generations of different models that way, sounds like bad database/model design. Are you sure you can't use less models with maybe related models via generic foreign keys and the parent-child relations to `self`?

Comment: It is an old project and mainly written by someone else. It can be rewritten of course (and it should be) but I don't have permissions for doing that. It seems to be working.

Comment: Generalised for all generations.

Comment: You could easily combine the child and descendant base classes into one. Just a matter of modifying `get_conf()` a little bit.